# Why do I have to use AND instead of a comma to separate the last item in the list?

Tags: mariadb

I'm writing a simple query to test some stuff and I realized that MariaDB will keep throwing an 1064 error if I don't use an AND to separate the last item in the WHERE statement. The following results in an error

```
SELECT
    re.ID_empl AS "ID Employee",
    cl.n_client AS "ID Client",
    cl.client_lastn AS "Client Last Name",
    car.Model AS "Car Model",
    car.Man AS "Manufacturer",
    car.Color AS "Color"
FROM
    Reserv AS re,
    Client AS cl,
    Cars AS car
WHERE
    re.ID_client = cl.ID_client, re.ID_Car = car.ID_Car ;
```

While the following one is executed without any problem

```
SELECT
    re.ID_empl AS "ID Employee",
    cl.n_client AS "ID Client",
    cl.client_lastn AS "Client Last Name",
    car.Model AS "Car Model",
    car.Man AS "Manufacturer",
    car.Color AS "Color"
FROM
    Reserv AS re,
    Client AS cl,
    Cars AS car
WHERE
    re.ID_client = cl.ID_client AND re.ID_Car = car.ID_Car ;
```

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find any other question on the same issue.

Comment: WHERE clause is a boolean expression not a list.

Comment: The WHERE clause is used to filter records. It is used to extract only those records that fulfill a specified condition. If you have more than one condition, you have to combine them with logical operators. (but not with a comma!)

Comment: You should use explicit `JOIN` syntax with `ON` clauses in your scenario anyway. But in `ON` clauses, as in `WHERE` clause a Boolean expression is expected.

Comment: I didn't know WHERE was a boolean expression, I was treating it just like comparison of a series of conditions. Now the use of a logical operator makes perfect sense. Thank you!